# Reshaping multiple groups of columns in a data frame from wide to long

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2, melt

I am working with air-quality data. I tried to reshape the data frame from wide to long using `melt` function. Here is the data: `Elev` stands for `Elevation`, `Obs` for `observation` and `US3, DK1, DE1` are models, where `lm` and `ul` represents first and third quantiles.

```
Elev      Obs       lm       ul      US3       lm       ul      DK1       lm       ul
1    0 37.74289 34.33422 41.27840 38.82037 35.35241 42.30042 49.31111 45.00134 53.90968
2  100 38.14076 34.71842 41.36560 39.82727 36.49086 43.22209 50.46545 45.79068 55.44664
3  250 39.31056 35.98180 42.50011 40.94909 37.70768 44.40232 50.79818 45.76405 55.54795
4  500 41.03098 37.78005 44.02544 42.54909 39.25627 45.72927 51.24182 46.76091 55.88568
5  750 43.57307 40.52575 46.92804 43.48000 40.55918 46.62914 51.90364 47.40586 56.37514
       DE1       lm       ul
1 41.15185 37.81824 44.62509
2 40.89455 37.38491 44.34759
3 40.93455 37.33400 44.32573
4 41.26727 37.90150 44.68568
5 43.04545 40.04541 46.12386
```

I used

```
 melt(f,id.vars=c("Elev", "lm","um"),measure.vars=c("US3", "DK1", "DE1","Obs" ))
```

and I got

```
Elev       lm       ul      variable    value
   0 34.33422 41.27840           US3 38.82037
 100 34.71842 41.36560           US3 39.82727
 250 35.98180 42.50011           US3 40.94909
 500 37.78005 44.02544           US3 42.54909
 750 40.52575 46.92804           US3 43.48000
   0 34.33422 41.27840           DK1 49.31111
 100 34.71842 41.36560           DK1 50.46545
 250 35.98180 42.50011           DK1 50.79818
 500 37.78005 44.02544           DK1 51.24182
 750 40.52575 46.92804           DK1 51.90364
   0 34.33422 41.27840           DE1 41.15185
 100 34.71842 41.36560           DE1 40.89455
 250 35.98180 42.50011           DE1 40.93455
 500 37.78005 44.02544           DE1 41.26727
 750 40.52575 46.92804           DE1 43.04545
   0 34.33422 41.27840           Obs 37.74289
 100 34.71842 41.36560           Obs 38.14076
 250 35.98180 42.50011           Obs 39.31056
 500 37.78005 44.02544           Obs 41.03098
 750 40.52575 46.92804           Obs 43.57307
```

As it can clearly be seen the values of `lm` and `ul` are repeated for every elevation. How can I have a long format without the repetition of those values?
My expected result is:

```
Elev    lm      ul      variable  value
  0 35.35241 42.30042      US3 38.82037
100 36.49086 43.22209      US3 39.82727
250 37.70768 44.40232      US3 40.94909
500 39.25627 45.72927      US3 42.54909
750 40.55918 46.62914      US3 43.48000
  0 45.00134 53.90968      DK1 49.31111
100 45.79068 55.44664      DK1 50.46545
250 45.76405 55.54795      DK1 50.79818
500 46.76091 55.88568      DK1 51.24182
750 47.40586 56.37514      DK1 51.90364
  0 37.81824 44.62509      DE1 41.15185
100 37.38491 44.34759      DE1 40.89455
250 37.33400 44.32573      DE1 40.93455
500 37.90150 44.68568      DE1 41.26727
750 40.04541 46.12386      DE1 43.04545
  0 34.33422 41.27840      Obs 37.74289
100 34.71842 41.36560      Obs 38.14076
250 35.98180 42.50011      Obs 39.31056
500 37.78005 44.02544      Obs 41.03098
750 40.52575 46.92804      Obs 43.57307
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the format you would like to see?

Comment: What would you want the output to look like? Do you want to discard those variables? Only include them once and then have `NA` below? Something else?

Comment: You specified `lm` and `ul` as id variables - `id.vars`. You have 20 unique data points and 5 ids. They have to be repeated by definition.

Comment: That's how "wide to long" works. If you don't want to see `Elev`, `lm` or `ul`, you could use _e.g._ `dplyr::select` to remove them before the melt. If you need them then don't worry: the next step in your procedure will deal with it.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); map(0:3, ~df[c(1, .x * 3 + 2:4)]) %>% map_df(~gather(.x, var, val, -Elev, -lm, -ul))`

Comment: @Scott Presnesll, I have updated the question to include the desired result.

Comment: @Nick Kennedy, neilfws,alistaire I have updated the question to include the desired result

Comment: You'd better first rename the columns in order to have unique names.

Comment: @skan, what do you mean rename columns? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Now you have different columns with the same name: Elev, Obs, lm, ul, US3, lm, ul, DK1, lm, ul, DE1, lm, ul.

Comment: @skan, you can modify the names as Obs.lm, Obs.ul, US3.lm,US3.ul ... etc and let me know if it works for you as I have tried that way too.

Comment: Something that would assist asking, finding and canonicalizing questions on this topic is a post I previously made on [MSO: "Tags/terms used for data-science concepts: reshape/wide-form/long-form/tall-form/stacked data/unstacked/melt/cast"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338268/tags-terms-used-for-data-science-concepts-reshape-wide-form-long-form-tall-form?noredirect=1#comment414043_338268). I got all sorts of sarcastic responses; even got someone sarcastically posting in [R Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106/r) claiming I made up the terms 'wide-form'/'long-form'.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a data.table and have your names as:
Elev, Obs_va, obs_lm, obs_ul, US3_va, US3_lm, US3_ul, DK1_va, DK1_lm, DK1_ul, DE1_va, DE1_lm, DE1_ul.

Then this code produces the expected result in a very generic way.

```
temp <- melt(temp, id.vars=c("Elev"))
temp[, `:=`(var = sub("_..$", '', variable),  measure = 
          sub('.*_', '', variable), variable = NULL)]  
dcast( temp[measure!="va",],   ... ~ measure, value.var='value' )
```

You could also pass the arguments manually instead.
Or just split and paste the data.table or data.frame manually in chunks.

And here you have another solution, simpler:

```
temp2 <- melt(temp, measure.vars=patterns("lm$","ul$"), 
   value.name = c("lm","ul"))[,c("Elev","variable","lm","ul")]
temp2[,"variable"] <- sub("_va","",grep("_va",names(temp), 
   value=T))[temp2$variable]
```

Where temp is your original data.table.

Answer (score 1):

The recent versions of `data.table` allow to [`melt` multiple columns simultaneously](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html)

An additional difficulty is that the data frame contains *columns with the same name*. Thanks to the `patterns()` function, it is *not* required to rename the columns beforehand.

```
library(data.table) # version 1.10.4 used here

# create vector of the names of data groups - in the order they appear in the DF !
dg_names <- c("Obs", "US3", "DK1", "DE1")

# coerce DF to data.table and melt using the patterns() function to identify columns
molten <- melt(setDT(DF), 
               measure.vars = patterns(paste(dg_names, collapse = "|"), "lm", "ul"), 
               value.name = c("value", "lm", "ul"))

# rename variable column to something meaningful
molten[, variable := factor(variable, labels = dg_names)]
```

Despite the different order of columns and rows, the result is as expected by the OP:

```
molten
#    Elev variable    value       lm       ul
# 1:    0      Obs 37.74289 34.33422 41.27840
# 2:  100      Obs 38.14076 34.71842 41.36560
# 3:  250      Obs 39.31056 35.98180 42.50011
# 4:  500      Obs 41.03098 37.78005 44.02544
# 5:  750      Obs 43.57307 40.52575 46.92804
# 6:    0      US3 38.82037 35.35241 42.30042
# 7:  100      US3 39.82727 36.49086 43.22209
# 8:  250      US3 40.94909 37.70768 44.40232
# 9:  500      US3 42.54909 39.25627 45.72927
#10:  750      US3 43.48000 40.55918 46.62914
#11:    0      DK1 49.31111 45.00134 53.90968
#12:  100      DK1 50.46545 45.79068 55.44664
#13:  250      DK1 50.79818 45.76405 55.54795
#14:  500      DK1 51.24182 46.76091 55.88568
#15:  750      DK1 51.90364 47.40586 56.37514
#16:    0      DE1 41.15185 37.81824 44.62509
#17:  100      DE1 40.89455 37.38491 44.34759
#18:  250      DE1 40.93455 37.33400 44.32573
#19:  500      DE1 41.26727 37.90150 44.68568
#20:  750      DE1 43.04545 40.04541 46.12386
```

#### Data

```
DF <- structure(list(Elev = c(0L, 100L, 250L, 500L, 750L), Obs = c(37.74289, 
38.14076, 39.31056, 41.03098, 43.57307), lm = c(34.33422, 34.71842, 
35.9818, 37.78005, 40.52575), ul = c(41.2784, 41.3656, 42.50011, 
44.02544, 46.92804), US3 = c(38.82037, 39.82727, 40.94909, 42.54909, 
43.48), lm = c(35.35241, 36.49086, 37.70768, 39.25627, 40.55918
), ul = c(42.30042, 43.22209, 44.40232, 45.72927, 46.62914), 
    DK1 = c(49.31111, 50.46545, 50.79818, 51.24182, 51.90364), 
    lm = c(45.00134, 45.79068, 45.76405, 46.76091, 47.40586), 
    ul = c(53.90968, 55.44664, 55.54795, 55.88568, 56.37514), 
    DE1 = c(41.15185, 40.89455, 40.93455, 41.26727, 43.04545), 
    lm = c(37.81824, 37.38491, 37.334, 37.9015, 40.04541), ul = c(44.62509, 
    44.34759, 44.32573, 44.68568, 46.12386)), .Names = c("Elev", 
"Obs", "lm", "ul", "US3", "lm", "ul", "DK1", "lm", "ul", "DE1", 
"lm", "ul"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @G1124E, please, can you give some feedback whether skan's and mine answers do meet your requirements or if you are missing something. Thank you.