# Converting data from wide to long for two variables

Tags: r, melt

I have a dataset with two variables in a wide format that I want to convert to long. I've seen the examples from the cook for R but they are for just one variable.

My dataset (graph.dat) looks like this:

```
 PH25   PH50    PH75    PH100   P25      P50    P75    P100      r_b    c
3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    1,694   1,736   1,329   800     0.029   7
2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    1,665   1,792   1,639   1,335   0.027   7
3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    1,580   1,560   1,156   663     0.023   7
```

I want to plot PH (x-axis) versus P(y-axis). So for a PH25 value corresponds a value of P25 (and a value of r_b and c); so the long format will be:

```
PH       P      r_b         c
3.96    1,694   0.029       7
2.86    1,665   0.027       7
3.96    1,580   0.023       7
5.94    1,736   0.029       7
2.86    1,792   0.027       7
5.72    1,560   0.023       7
5.94    1,329   0.029       7
2.86    1,639   0.027       7
5.72    1,156   0.023       7
5.94    800     0.029       7
2.86    1,335   0.027       7
5.72    663     0.023       7
```

I try to "melt" it twice but it doesn't work.
Here is what I did:

```
graph.dat1<- melt(graph.dat, id.vars=c("PH25","PH50","PH75",
                                        "PH100","r_b", "c"),
                             variable.name="P", 
                             value.name="Pval")
```

and the new dataset (graph.dat1) is fine because I've only three values for each "P" (giving me a total of 12 observations). It looks like this:

```
    PH25    PH50    PH75    PH100   r_b     c    P     Pval
1   3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    0.029   7   P25    1694
2   2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    0.027   7   P25    1665
3   3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    0.023   7   P25    1580
4   3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    0.029   7   P50    1736
5   2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    0.027   7   P50     1792
6   3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    0.023   7   P50     1560
7   3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    0.029   7   P75     1329
8   2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    0.027   7   P75     1639
9   3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    0.023   7   P75     1156
10  3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    0.029   7   P100    800
11  2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    0.027   7   P100    1335
12  3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    0.023   7   P100    663
```

but when I do the second "melt" it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve it. This is the second step I did:

```
graph.dat2<- melt (graph.dat1,id.vars=c("r_b", "c", "P", "Pval"),
                   variable.name="PdH",
                   value.name="PH")
```

but then I get 4 times the number of observations (so instead of 12 observations I get 48 observations). So, my new dataset (graph.dat2) looks like:

```
    r_b     c   P     Pval  PdH      PH
1   0.029   7   P25   1694  PH25    3.96
2   0.027   7   P25   1665  PH25    2.86
3   0.023   7   P25   1580  PH25    3.96
4   0.029   7   P50   1736  PH25    3.96
5   0.027   7   P50   1792  PH25    2.86
6   0.023   7   P50   1560  PH25    3.96
7   0.029   7   P75   1329  PH25    3.96
8   0.027   7   P75   1639  PH25    2.86
9   0.023   7   P75   1156  PH25    3.96
10  0.029   7   P100   800  PH25    3.96
11  0.027   7   P100  1335  PH25    2.86
12  0.023   7   P100   663  PH25    3.96
13  0.029   7   P25   1694  PH50    5.94
14  0.027   7   P25   1665  PH50    2.86
15  0.023   7   P25   1580  PH50    5.72
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent versions of `data.table` allow to [`melt` multiple columns simultaneously](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html).

Unfortunately, both sets of columns start with the letter `P`. Simply specifying `patterns("PH", "P")` won't work as `P` will match the `PH` columns as well as the `P` columns resulting in 24 rows instead of 12. The slightly modified regular expressions `patterns("PH", "P\\d")` will work:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
graph.dat1 <- melt(setDT(graph.dat), measure.vars = patterns("PH", "P\\d"), 
     value.name = c("PH", "P"))
# rename factor levels of variable
graph.dat1[, variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, c("25", "50", "75", "100"))][]
```

> ```
>       r_b c variable   PH     P
>  1: 0.029 7       25 3.96 1,694
>  2: 0.027 7       25 2.86 1,665
>  3: 0.023 7       25 3.96 1,580
>  4: 0.029 7       50 5.94 1,736
>  5: 0.027 7       50 2.86 1,792
>  6: 0.023 7       50 5.72 1,560
>  7: 0.029 7       75 5.94 1,329
>  8: 0.027 7       75 2.86 1,639
>  9: 0.023 7       75 5.72 1,156
> 10: 0.029 7      100 5.94   800
> 11: 0.027 7      100 2.86 1,335
> 12: 0.023 7      100 5.72   663
> ```

Note that it is required to coerce `graph.dat` to a `data.table` object by using either `setDT(graph.dat)` or `data.table(graph.dat)`. Otherwise, `reshape2::melt()` would be dispatched on a data.frame object which doesn't recognize `patterns()`.

Also note, there is an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43154370/3817004) but the required `patterns()` are quite different.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
graph.dat <- fread(
"PH25   PH50    PH75    PH100   P25      P50    P75    P100      r_b    c
3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    1,694   1,736   1,329   800     0.029   7
2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    1,665   1,792   1,639   1,335   0.027   7
3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    1,580   1,560   1,156   663     0.023   7",
data.table = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Uwe Block! I did see the question and answers you mention but I thought it had only one variable. Now, that I see your answer to my question I have a better understanding of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution in base R would be:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="PH25   PH50    PH75    PH100   P25          P50    P75    P100      r_b    c
3.96    5.94    5.94    5.94    1,694   1,736   1,329   800     0.029   7
2.86    2.86    2.86    2.86    1,665   1,792   1,639   1,335   0.027   7
3.96    5.72    5.72    5.72    1,580   1,560   1,156   663     0.023   7")

(want<-do.call(rbind,
               Map(
                 function(x,y) data.frame(PH=df[[x]],P=df[[y]],r_b=df$r_b,c=df$c),
                 c("PH25","PH50","PH75","PH100"),
                 c("P25","P50","P75","P100")
                 )))
```

Comment: Thanks r.user.05apr! I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

not too difficult with base R `reshape` either:

```
reshape(df, direction="long", varying=list(paste0("PH", 1:4*25), paste0("P", 1:4*25)))
# note: paste0("PH", 1:4*25) is shortcut for c("PH25", "PH50", "PH75", "PH100")
```

.. to set the names right (`PH` instead of `PH25` in the long format):

```
reshape(df, direction="long", varying=list(paste0("PH", 1:4*25), paste0("P", 1:4*25)),
    v.names=c("PH", "P"))
```